# Apache - 403 Forbidden

Tags: permissions, apache-httpd

I know this question has been asked a lot of times but I'm completely stucked.
My `/var/www/html` folder contains:

```
mbfr/
|-- index.html
|
school/
|-- index.html
```

I want to `exemple.com` serves the `mbfr` directory and `exemple.com/school` serves the `school` directory. Here is my `VirtualHosts` config file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName exemple.com

    ServerAdmin xxxxx@exemple.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    Alias / /mbfr
    Alias /school /school

    <Directory "/var/www/html/school">
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory "/var/www/html/mbfr">
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

`exemple.com` works fine but `exemple.com/school` gives me

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /school/ on this server.
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the correct permissions set on the */school folder? I had the same 403 message recently after reinstalling a folder in /var/www/html after an OS upgrade. It turned out that the premissions on the individual files were ok but on the folder only I myself as owner had read, write and execution permissions. Group and others also needed read and execution permissions so a simple `chmod a+rx` did the trick for me. Could be worth checking.

Answer (score 1):

Please understand that my answer below is not an actual solution but a workaround, as it removes a security enforcement around httpd and the effects of this action can not be predicted. Although, until you figure out what a good and permanent solution is, it works.

as root user on your server, execute the commands below

```
setenforce 0
service httpd start
```

the `setenforce 0` command puts apache in to SELinux Permissive mode. As I am not a web administrator and have no intrinsic knowledge of apache, I am not aware of repercussions of this action. Maybe someone can enlighten both of us. Since my webserver is not anything critical, I really could not care less. I am okay if I have to install the server from scratch. But your case might be different. So, take my advice with a grain of salt. A large grain at that.